# Adding comment to the pull request throws "Message: Not Found" error

Tags: github-api-v3

I am trying to add commit to the pull request using GitHub API for issues. But seeing error

curl -H "Authorization: token "Key"" -X POST -d '{"body": "Failed"}' "https://github-site/repos/:repository/issues/PR_NUMBER/comments"

Response for the curl command.

{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.15/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment"
}

Answer (score 1):

Ah I found my mistake. I was passing basic authorizing keys. To Post the comment or to create a Label we need OAUTH token generated on github.

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/